# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Files.readAllBytes(path)

Tags: java, spring, file

I'm converting a big file (18 GB) to a byte[], but I got this error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This is the code responsable for the exception:

```
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

I'm creating the byte array to send it over network:

```
createFile(filename.toString(),content);

private ADLStoreClient client; // package com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store
public boolean createFile(String filename, byte[] content) {
        try {
            // create file and write some content
            OutputStream stream = client.createFile(filename, IfExists.OVERWRITE);
            // set file permission
            client.setPermission(filename, "777");
            // append to file
            stream.write(content);
            stream.close();

        } catch (ADLException ex) {
            printExceptionDetails(ex);
            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(" Exception: {}", ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Obviouslly readAllBytes() reads all bytes into memory and cause the OutOfMemoryError, I think this is can be solved using streams but I'm not good at them, can anybody give a proper solution, thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Azure [ADLStoreClient documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store._a_d_l_store_client.createfile?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_datalake_store__a_d_l_store_client_createFile_String_IfExists_) states:

> `createFile(String path, IfExists mode)`
>
> create a file. If `overwriteIfExists` is false and the file already exists, then an exceptionis thrown. The call returns an `ADLFileOutputStream` that can then be written to.

So something like this:

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
     OutputStream out = client.createFile(filename, IfExists.OVERWRITE)) {
    IOUtils.copyLarge(in, out);
}
```

You can get `IOUtils` from `commons-io` or make the [`copyLarge`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#line.2206) routine yourself, it's very simple:

```
void copyLarge(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (if you like to process it line-by-line)

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            stream.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a file Stream class that i use to read files to stream:

```
/**
 * Allows a file to be read and iterated over and allow to take advantage of java streams
 * @author locus2k
 *
 */
public class FileStream implements Iterator<byte[]>, Iterable<byte[]>, Spliterator<byte[]> {

  private InputStream stream;
  private int bufferSize;
  private long blockCount;


  /**
   * Create a FileStreamReader
   * @param stream the input stream containing the content to be read
   * @param bufferSize size of the buffer that should be read at once from the stream
   */
  private FileStream(InputStream stream, long fileSize, int bufferSize) {
    this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    //calculate how many blocks will be generated by this stream
    this.blockCount = (long) Math.ceil((float)fileSize / (float)bufferSize);
    this.stream = stream;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    boolean hasNext = false;
    try {
      hasNext = stream.available() > 0;
      return hasNext;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return false;
    } finally {
      //close the stream if there is no more to read
      if (!hasNext) {
        close();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] next() {
    try {
      byte[] data = new byte[Math.min(bufferSize, stream.available())];
      stream.read(data);
      return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //Close the stream if next causes an exception
      close();
      throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Close the stream
   */
  public void close() {
    try {
      stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super byte[]> action) {
    action.accept(next());
    return hasNext();
  }

  @Override
  public Spliterator<byte[]> trySplit() {
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public long estimateSize() {
    return blockCount;
  }

  @Override
  public int characteristics() {
    return Spliterator.IMMUTABLE;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<byte[]> iterator() {
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super byte[]> action) {
    while(hasNext())
      action.accept(next());
  }

  /**
   * Create a java stream
   * @param inParallel if true then the returned stream is a parallel stream; if false the returned stream is a sequential stream.
   * @return stream with the data
   */
  private Stream<byte[]> stream(boolean inParallel) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(this, inParallel);
  }

  /**
   * Create a File Stream reader
   * @param fileName Name of the file to stream
   * @param bufferSize size of the buffer that should be read at once from the stream
   * @return Stream representation of the file
   */
  public static Stream<byte[]> stream(String fileName, int bufferSize) {
    return stream(new File(fileName), bufferSize);
  }

  /**
   * Create a FileStream reader
   * @param file The file to read
   * @param bufferSize the size of each read
   * @return the stream
   */
  public static Stream<byte[]> stream(File file, int bufferSize) {
    try {
      return stream(new FileInputStream(file), bufferSize);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Create a file stream reader
   * @param stream the stream to read from (note this process will close the stream)
   * @param bufferSize size of each read
   * @return the stream
   */
  public static Stream<byte[]> stream(InputStream stream, int bufferSize) {
    try {
      return new FileStream(stream, stream.available(), bufferSize).stream(false);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the number of segments that will be created
   * @param sourceSize the size of the file
   * @param bufferSize the buffer size (or chunk size for each segment to be)
   * @return the number of packets that will be created
   */
  public static long caculateEstimatedSize(long sourceSize, Integer bufferSize) {
    return (long) Math.ceil((float)sourceSize / (float)bufferSize);
  }
}
```

Then to use it you can do something like

```
FileStream.stream("myfile.text", 30000).forEach(b -> System.out.println(b.length));
```

This will create a file stream and each call in forEach will return a byte array the size of the buffer specified in this case the byte array will be 30,000.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said you try to put 18 GB in memory (RAM) so you can
use -Xmsn and set it to 18 GB but you will need free 18 GB of memory you can read about it in java docs: [-Xmsn Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard)